# Entityframework duplicating when calling savechanges

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am using entityframework 5 code first, I have a model like this.

```
class Product {
    public Product() {
        Fabrics = new BindingList<FabricLineItem>();
    }
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<FabricLineItem> Fabrics { get;set; }
}

class FabricLineItem {
    [ForeignKey("Fabric")]
    public int FabricId { get; set; }  
    public virtual Product Product { get;set; }
    public virtual Fabric Fabric { get;set; }  
}

class Fabric {
    ...
}
```

I already have fabrics in my database. I create a new product object and add some fabriclineitems to the collection. When I try to save product what happens is it duplicates the fabric in the database and reference it to the new one after calling

```
 DataContext.SaveChanges();
```

Before the call to savechanges the values in the debugger are correct by after calling they are changed ? Any idea why I am getting this strange behavior ?

Comment: Why do you have `FabricId` and `virtual Fabric` in your `FabricLineItem`? Shouldn't only `virtual Fabric` be enough? How are you adding `FabricLineItems` to a `Product`?

Comment: First I tried only with that.. But then I tried to explicitly set the fabricid and then tried to save but it didn't work either.

Comment: Can you give us more details about actual data model you are trying to implement? What is `FabricLineItem`? Could you not just associate `Fabric` with `Product`?

Comment: Actually the product is going to have some fabrics [these are like raw material] so I created I fabriclineitem which links fabrics to product and also has some fields that what quantity of fabric is used for what part of the product. This is what you are asking ?

Comment: Your code does not have the part how you save it. you need get fabric object not Id to save it. If the fabric object is not loaded , only use id to do it.

Comment: When I check the DataContext object in the debugger the Object and the fabric id both are populated with correct values but after calling savechanges they are changed :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect that the context does not know that the Fabrics are not new items - so it adds/inserts them.

If you attach the fabrics to the DataContext (as Unchanged/NotModified) - or select them from the database, then when SaveChanges() is called the context knows about existing Fabric objects and can then just create a navigation relationship for the new FabricLineItem without creating a new Fabric

EF is a lot 'dumber' than it looks - you really need to tell it almost everything.

Answer (score 12):

I was also having the problem of E.F. not recognising that an item already existed when it was referenced within another new object to be added to the DB.

@NeilThompson gave me the clue above how to solve this:

You need to attach an existing entity to the context so that it knows that it already exists:

For example:

```
context.Fabrics.Attach(product.Fabric); 
context.Products.Add(product);
context.SaveChanges();

return organisation;
```

I got this from here:

"If you have an entity that you know already exists in the database but which is not currently being tracked by the context then you can tell the context to track the entity using the Attach method on DbSet. The entity will be in the Unchanged state in the context."

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/01/29/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-4-add-attach-and-entity-states.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Based on additional info from the comments: you would need to add FabricLineItemID (primary key) to your FabricLineItem class/entity and remove FabricId (EF will create a foreign key for you). When you create a new FabricLineItem, to be associated with a Product, get a Fabric record from the database and then associate it with the newly created FabricLineItem, then get the product and associate it with the FabricLineItem. You don't need to create a new list in Product's constructor, EF will do the rest.

Comment: Id is already there.. here you go to see the actual classes. https://gist.github.com/ahmednasir91/428c11695312635bc43f

Comment: You mean I should first save the product and then save the lineitems ? Actually I have binded this model with the view so the product screen has got both the list of lineitems and other product fields.

Comment: Whoa, this is more involved than I thought. However, I think if you lose `FabricId` from `FabriLineItem` and make sure you are adding an existing Fabric (that you retrieved from DB) to the product, you should be fine. Also, don't create a new list in Product's constructor. I think when you are adding line items to that list it might actually be duplicating the records in memory. EF would change the IDs of those line items (creating new records in DB) when you save. You don't need to save Product first - create a new Product, add it to your new line item. That should do.