# Prevent EF default behaviour of saving duplicates via populated navigation properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Imagine this pair of entities in Entity Framework:

```
public class Price
{
  public virtual Document Document { get; set; }
  public int DocumentId { get; set; }
  //stuff
}

public class Document
{
    public int DocumentId { get; set; }
    //stuff
}
```

It's well known that if you populate the Document object in this pairing it can result in duplicates of existing objects, as explained here: [Entityframework duplicating when calling savechanges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15394207/entityframework-duplicating-when-calling-savechanges) - the solution is to only populate the key field before saving.

However, consider this situation in creating new objects.

```
Price price = repository.GetPriceById(1);
Document doc = new Document();
```

Right now that document has no Id, because the `DocumentId` field is an `IDENTITY` and it hasn't been sent to the database - it's just a virtual in-memory object. I can't get an Id for it unless I save it, and I don't want to do that at this point: the requirement is for a one-button save, not partial saves as the code works through. So, if I want to attach it to the Price object, I therefore have no way of making that association other than to assign it directly to the Document property. If I save it in that state, I'll get a duplicate.

So when I save it, I'm forced to do this:

```
repository.UpdatePrice(price.Document);
repository.SaveChanges();

price.DocumentId = price.Document.DocumentId;
price.Document = null;
repository.SaveChanges();
```

In which the set to null just seems ridiculous: there's no obvious reason for doing so and it feels like a future maintenance issue in waiting. All the more so because the one-click-save requirement means we have this problem all over the codebase. Is there any other way to deal with this issue?

Comment: so, you want to modify the price's document, not add a new one, correct? If you `.Include` the Document when you load the price then Entity Framework (IIRC) updates it without adding a new entity. Or do you want to set the price's Document to the newly created `doc`? In that case, it **should** add a new entity - it's a new object, right?

Comment: @Default right - the problem is that EF isn't "aware" that the existing Price object already exists. So when you save it with an attached Document, it thinks we've got two prices - the original, and the one on the virtual property - and creates a duplicate. The linked question explains the problem.

Comment: Even if the `Price` has an `Id` property?

Comment: again, IIRC, when you want to update an existing entity via Entity Framework you have to either fetch it or attach it inside the `using (DbContext db = new DbContext(){ }`. Can you add a complete example if your issue?

Comment: @Default Yes. It keeps the old one, and adds a new copy with a new Id.

Comment: It is not an issue, let alone to be a *well-known* issue to EntityFramework. It is all about this simple fact that you should tell any ORM what entity is new and what is not. In your case, context should somehow know `Document` is the new entity.

Comment: @Default as is often the case with EF questions it's kind of hard to provide a working example without posting reams of code.

Comment: @Alireza I didn't say it was an issue. It's by design. I'm trying to find out how best to handle it in this situation.

Comment: @MattThrower Is the `price` entity attached to context? I don't guess it is attached. So, first attach it, modify it, save...or...Retrieve it by Id, modify it, save.

Comment: It shouldn't be hard to provide a small working example. But sure - can we then assume that all the code you provided is at least inside **one** DbContext scope? Are the attached when you try to save? Are they fetched again? What does `UpdatePrice` do?

Comment: @Default all fair comments. I'll see what I can do. We're getting fresh contexts for each transaction batch, which is certainly part of the problem.

Comment: `Price price = repository.GetPriceById(1);` => is price retrieved from an entity context ?? or is it detached from context ?

Comment: @EmmanuelM It's retrieved from a context, but then the save transaction is performed on a fresh context.

Comment: @MattThrower Tell the *Fresh Context* `price` is not new.

Comment: and did you try using this kind of synthax : `context.Entry(price).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;` ?

Comment: @Alireza Just tried that, and it's not helping. Which is frustrating because I can understand the logic of what you're suggesting. I must be doing something else wrong.

Comment: @MattThrower Can you post the repository code? Or a simple project depicting your problem?

Comment: which object is duplicated ? Price or Document, if your price ID is the right one i don't see how you could duplicate it this way.

Comment: @Alireza It looks like there may be another virtual property on the actual object causing the dupe - it may be I need to attach that. But you're right - I'm going to have to isolate this into a test if I expect any more help. Thanks for your assistance so far.