# Entity code first duplicate entries (MVC Identity)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

Until now I have always worked with my own DAL for SQL Server.
In a new project I decided to work with Entity in a MVC project and Identity.
I use to work with bridge tables.
Here is my IdentityModels (simplified)

**ApplicationUser**

```
 public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
 {
    [Required]
    public string Surname { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Group> Groups { get; set; }
 }
```

**Group**

```
public class Group
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Nom du Groupe")]
    [Required]
    [CustomRemoteValidation("IsGroupNameExist", "Groups", AdditionalFields = 
    "Id")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers { get; set; 
}
```

**And DbContext**

```
 public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }

    public DbSet<Group> Groups { get; set; }
}
```

All tables I need are created and seems well created (`ApplicationUser` `Group` and `ApplicationUserGroups`).

The trouble is :
I have 3 groups (A, B, C) with Id 1,2,3. I"m adding a user in table `ApplicationUser` with 3 groups in the `Groups` property.
First part is OK, it adds the good values in the bridge table (`ApplicationUsersGroup`) BUT It adds groups A, B, C again, with Id 4,5,6 in `Group` table.

The `CreateAsync` method of `UserManager`is not the point (It's the same with just an `Add`).
If I have a look in the debugger, I can see that when I pass to the add method the user object, in the `Groups`property, I have a `ApplicationUsers` property with inside the `Groups` property. For me, it could be the reason, but if I remove the `Groups` property from `ApplicationUser`, code first doesn't create the `ApplicationUserGroups`.

I'm wrong with something, but what? How can I have a user without an additional entry in `Group`table?

Thank you for your help.

***UPDATE***

Ok, now I understood why duplicates are added, but in my case, how to avoid that?
Here is the involved part of the `Register` method:

```
 List<Group> selectedItems = new List<Group>();
 foreach (GroupTableViewModel item in model.SelectedGroups)
 {
     if (item.Selected == true) selectedItems.Add(new Group { Id = item.Id, Name = item.GroupName });
 }

  var  user = new ApplicationUser { Name = model.Name, Surname = model.Surname, UserName = model.Surname + "." + model.Name, Email = model.Email,Groups=selectedItems};
  string password = RandomPassword.Generate(8, 8);

  var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, password);
```

`CreateAsync()` is the identity method. I don't understand how it adds the user (I don't see any `Add()` or `'SaveChanges()` inside with JustDecompile).
Maybe I'm wrong again but if I want to attach an entity to the context I have to create a new context, which will be different from the context used by the `CreateAsync()` method.

So help needed...

Comment: One user will be in multiple group?

Comment: Yes a user could be in multiple groups and a group could have many users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common issue that people unfamiliar with EF face.  Because of the disconnected state of entities in the object context, EF will attempt to insert the entities in the relationships, even though they already exist.  In order to solve, you need to tell EF that the entities are not new by setting their state to Unchanged.  Take a look at this article from Julie Lerman and the related SO question/answer.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn166926.aspx

[Entityframework duplicating when calling savechanges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15394207/entityframework-duplicating-when-calling-savechanges)